# Android: Access a fragment instance from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've started coding a small app using Android Studio's pre-defined tabbed Layout with Fragments (SectionsPagerAdapter, ViewPager).

I've got a task running in the MainActivity.class main/Ui thread which at one point shows a dialog with the onClick method

```
@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            category = eventsToDisplay.get(which);
            averageFragment.category = category;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

But I can't get the `averageFragment.category = category;` assignment to work.

In the MainActivity's onCreate method I call `averageFragment = (AverageFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AverageFragment.tag);` but this gives me a NullPointerException.

I have already tried the following solutions (most of which are from this website):

- `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_average)`
- `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AverageFragment.tag)` <-- basically a static variable created upon instantiating the fragment.
- `mSectionsPageAdapter.getItem(1)`

all of which give me either a NPE or IllegalStateException.FragmentNotAttachedToView.

Other relevant code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return InspectionFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 1:
                return AverageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 2:
                return RegulationsFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to access the fragment from the main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the location where you assign the instance of your adapter to the pager. The exception your getting means that the fragment hasn't loaded to the view yet, which is likely given that you're calling your assignment:

```
averageFragment = (AverageFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AverageFragment.tag);
```

from the onCreate() method. Try moving this assignment to the onResume(), which should ensure that your fragment has been loaded into the view and is accessible through the supportFragmentManager. Also make sure this assignment is occurring after you set the pager's adapter within the lifecycle of your activity.